# c# NPOI Excel set page number

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi

Would it be possible to set a page number for my Excel document? I have already set a page break after a certain amount of rows so I was wondering if I can do something with that?

Also, would it be possible to get the total amount of page breaks?

```
for (int j = 0; j < Input.Count; j++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(j + 2);
    if (internalCounter == limit)
    {
        sheet.SetRowBreak(j+1);
        internalCounter = 0;
    }
    ICell cellZero = row.CreateCell(0);
    ICell cellOne = row.CreateCell(1);
    ICell cellTwo = row.CreateCell(2);
    ICell cellThree = row.CreateCell(3);
    ICell cellFour = row.CreateCell(4);
    ICell cellFive = row.CreateCell(5);
    cellZero.CellStyle = contentStyle;
    cellOne.CellStyle = contentStyle;
    cellTwo.CellStyle = contentStyle;
    cellThree.CellStyle = contentStyle;
    cellFour.CellStyle = contentStyle;
    cellFive.CellStyle = contentStyle;

    cellZero.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString((internalCounter+1).ToString()));
    cellOne.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString(Input[j].BranchCode.ToString()));
    cellTwo.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString(Input[j].PolicyNo.ToString()));
    cellThree.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString(Input[j].Employer.ToString()));
    cellFour.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString(Input[j].Name.ToString()));
    cellFive.SetCellValue(cH.CreateRichTextString(Input[j].SerialNo.ToString()));

    internalCounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1: You can create a page header with page number:

```
var header = sheet.Header;    
header.Center = $"Page {HeaderFooter.Page}";
```

2: You can include the total number of pages in this header:

```
var header = sheet.Header;
header.Center = $"Page {HeaderFooter.Page} of {HeaderFooter.NumPages}";
```

3: If you want the total number of page breaks in code, add this:

```
var totalPageBreaks = 0;
for (int j = 0; j <  < Input.Count; j++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(j + 2);
    if (internalCounter == limit)
    {
        totalPageBreaks++;
        sheet.SetRowBreak(j + 1);
        internalCounter = 0;
    }
```

4: NPOI default is set to fit all on one page. Add this to get page breaks:

```
sheet.FitToPage = false;
```

5: Here is a demo Windows console application showing all the above points:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        var sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
        sheet.FitToPage = false;

        const int limit = 30;
        var internalCounter = 0;
        var totalPageBreaks = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(j + 2);
            if (internalCounter == limit)
            {
                totalPageBreaks++;
                sheet.SetRowBreak(j + 1);
                internalCounter = 0;
            }

            ICell cellZero = row.CreateCell(0);
            ICell cellOne = row.CreateCell(1);

            cellZero.SetCellValue($"Counter {internalCounter + 1}");
            cellOne.SetCellValue($"BranchCode {j + 1}");
            internalCounter++;
        }

        var header = sheet.Header;
        header.Center = $"Page {HeaderFooter.Page} of {HeaderFooter.NumPages}";

        using (var file = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\Test1.xls", FileMode.Create))
        {
            wb.Write(file);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Worksheet created. Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: NPOI excel demo result]